# Synchronous Sleep function in Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, sleep, pausing-execution

I want to simulate a progress bar using JS/JQuery, this is my HTML code :

```
<p id="percentage">0%</p>
```

I want to go from 0 to 100 and see -Visually- the progress in slow motion, So What I need exactly is a For Loop and a pause function, but unfortunately there is no sleep-like function in `Javascript`

### 1st try :

After doing some research, I found the `setTimeOut` function in `Jquery`,  you can find herein the `Javascript` code :

```
for (i = 0; i < 100; i++) { 
    setTimeout(function() {
        $("#percentage").text(i+"%");
    }, 1000);
}
```

But unlikely, this won't work, because according to the documentation the `setTimeout` function is asynchronous, and the execution of the `Javascript` will continue. That means that there is no pause-like behavior, and the progress bar will go from 0 to 100 after 1000ms instead of going from 0 to 1.

### 2nd try :

While setTimeout can't solve my problem, I tried to implement my own sleep() function, and here it is :

```
function sleep(ms){
    var waitTimeInMilliseconds = new Date().getTime() + ms;
    while(new Date().getTime() < waitTimeInMilliseconds ) true;
}
```

While I was thinking that this is the silver bullet to this scenario -It was a bad Idea, I know-, I was surprised since also this approach didn't solve my problem, and the interface remains Idle during the sleep time, (I cannot click, select or do anything in my HTML page).

How can I solve this problem ?

Comment: Use `setTimeout()` the way it was intended to be used. Start a timer, and in the handler make the change you want to make and then start the timer again. Keep doing that until there are no more incremental changes.

Comment: First part of your problem: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/750486/javascript-closure-inside-loops-simple-practical-example, but there are better ways to implement it.

Comment: Have a look at the [setInterval()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowTimers.setInterval) function.

Comment: Nitpick, but this the title of the question should be changed.  All answers are for asynchronous `sleep()` because asker actually wants asynchronous `sleep()`; this is a red herring for people actually looking for a synchronous `sleep()`, e.g. for testing JS eventing bugs regarding very slow JS functions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You'd probably want something a bit like this using [setInterval](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowTimers.setInterval):

```
var i = 0;
var intervalId;
intervalId = setInterval(function() {
    $("#pourcentage").text(i+"%");
    if(i >= 100){
        clearInterval(intervalId);
    }
    i++;
}, 1000);
```

or using [setTimeout](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowTimers.setTimeout) instead:

```
var i = 0;
var scheduleNextTimeout; 
scheduleNextTimeout = function(){
    setTimeout(function() {
        $("#pourcentage").text(i+"%");
        if(i < 100){
            scheduleNextTimeout();
        }
        i++;
    }, 1000);
};
scheduleNextTimeout();
```

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest the use of a recursive function for this.

```
function doProgress (startingPercent, interval) {
    var percent = startingPercent++;

    window.setTimeout(function () {
        $('#percentage').text(percent.toString() + '%');

        if (percent < 100) {
            doProgress(percent, interval);
        }
    }, interval);
}
```