# JavaScript pause function

Tags: javascript

I have a problem with my function - I need to pause the function for 10 secs and then to begin from where it left off but instead it(the clock) freezes for more than 10 secs and then continues after 13 secs - there is something I am doing wrong, could you please help me with it. Thank you all!!!

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/balkics/ncnpk5Le/1/

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26976925/synchronous-sleep-function-in-javascript